# Dell Optiplex 960 will not boot

Tags: boot, hard-drive-failure

I had to power my desktop down by holding the power button on until it shut down. Now when I press the power button the green light flashes a few moments  on the number 3 on the harddrive and then goes out. I also notice orange lights flashing across the numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you asking? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Does anything appear on screen? Is this PC under warranty?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're seeing a diagnostic light code.

Since it's not clear from the question which lights are flashing, I would refer to the [service manual for your desktop](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-960_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) (pages 139-142) and look for the symptoms you're seeing. You may want to edit your question later to better describe what you're seeing, in case someone else comes across this and has a similar problem.